# Sequence Diagram context menu absent in Visual Studio 2012 but was there in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sequence-diagram, contextmenu

I used to be able to generate sequence diagrams in Visual Studio 2010 by right-clicking within a function and selecting the appropriate menu option.

I just installed Visual Studio Premium 2012 (11.0.51106.01 Update 1)
and that menu option is not available. My project is in C#.

We had one other VS2012 patch in our library that I installed as well, but that did not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare) comparison page, Sequence Diagrams (and UML in general) can only be created by Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. The Premium edition can only read them.